# How to delete all text in a text file on ftp server without deleting file itself in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp

Hi I am doing a chat orientated program in vb.net. I have everything working nicely but there is a feature I am trying to add where if the user types /clear it will then delete the chat text from the file, (the chat is an ftp connection and it writes to a text file)

i'm hoping to only delete text from the file not the whole file itself, i have tried appending but that as you probably know already just writes extra text to the file.

If anyone can help it would be great cheers :D

Comment: what is wrong with deleting the file and creating a new one or replacing the file with a newly created file/overwrite the existing one? you could use the WriteAllText method in the File object and give it an empty string and it will overwrite the contents with just an empty string however this will only work for LOCAL files, not remote files.

Comment: The problem is that i'm trying to make it as portable as possible and i really do not wish to have any more files in the "bin" and have to have it with it all the time, also the network i'm using (school, (Softare Project yr 9))it does not allow uploading of files, but it does allow downloads, (Firewall policy)

Comment: Is there a way to re create the file on the ftp server overwriting the old file? So say if i create a file with the webrequest and it has the same name will it over write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go should be upload a new empty file overwriting the one on the FTP, with the same filename and path.

```
Dim wcFTP As New WebClient()

'wcFTP.Proxy = ...
wcFTP.BaseAddress = "ftp://foobar.domain.com"
wcFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass") 

Dim sFilePath As String '= ...
Dim sFtpPath As String = wcFTP.BaseAddress & sFolder & Path.GetFileName(sFilePath)

wcFTP.UploadFile(sFtpPath, sFilePath)
```

Where `sFilePath` is the path of the empty file with the same name as the one in the server.

---

To get an empty file you can donwload and empty the file on the ftp, or simply create a new file with the same name and no data. For example:

```
Dim sFilePath As String = "C:\Folder\fileName.xml"
File.Create(sFilePath).Dispose()
```

Comment: Ok i see, hmm ok um now the only problem i can possibly see there is would it be possible to have just the file name next to sFile

Comment: Like when you open a file like  (dim sreader as new system.IO.streamreader  sreader.openfile("txtDocument.txt") which is located in the same folder where the exe is

Comment: I don't think I understand you... to get the filename only of a full file path you can use this method: `sFileName = Path.GetFileName(sFullPath)`